# Conflict with multiple SDcard readers of the same brand connected at the same time

Tags: disk, storage, block-device, usb-device, lsusb

I have some Lexar UHS-II card readers (I believe the model is LRWM05U-7000), and when I connect more than one I realize some operations read/write from/to the wrong reader. Some apps do not even detect the second card reader connected.

Running `lsusb -v` I observe all information of both card readers is exactly the same, except for the device number:

```
2c2
< Bus 004 Device 004: ID 05dc:b055 Lexar Media, Inc. UHS2 RDR
---
> Bus 004 Device 005: ID 05dc:b055 Lexar Media, Inc. UHS2 RDR
```

Even their **serial numbers are the same!**, and I have 6 of them.

- How to make the apps recognize the readers as different devices and avoid the errors I'm getting?
- Is is it possible to change their serial numbers? I know some Bluetooth dongles allow changing their meta information, but I'm not sure how to do it on USB card readers.
- Maybe change how Linux recognize the readers on different ports that have the very same meta data?

[image: Lexar UHS-II card reader]

Comment: What os are you using and do you connect them over a usb hub or directly?

Comment: I'm using Linux (Debian), and I am connecting it directly to the computer.